# undefined method for _path, but route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, routes

I am getting a Rails error when i create a new "car_image"... the AJAX response is

```
undefined method `car_image_path' for #<CarImage:0x007fdbb1b79258>
```

Route defined

```
resources :car_images, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

Rake Routes

```
car_images GET    /car_images(.:format)                  car_images#index
POST   /car_images(.:format)                  car_images#create
car_image DELETE /car_images/:id(.:format)              car_images#destroy
```

However, the route is setup and i can see it when i rake routes, so i am not sure what the issue is. I am using the route in my model method:

```
class CarImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car

  attr_accessible :description, :image, :title, :car_id, :file

  mount_uploader :file, CarImageUploader

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:file),
      "size" => file.size,
      "url" => file.url,
      "thumbnail_url" => file.thumb.url,
      "delete_url" => car_image_path(:id => id),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end

end
```

What would be causing the undefined method here? The record does save, but i get the error response...

Comment: I can't see the route

Comment: i editted the question showing the rake routes printout

Comment: oh, you're in a model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need a link in a model (which should not be), add this inside:

```
delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'
```

Then replace:

```
car_image_path(:id => id)
```

With:

```
url_helpers.car_image_path(self)
```

Comment: Is there a better approach that you could recommend here? what about maybe just hardcoding the path, rather than using the URL helper?

Comment: I think I know a better way, in my view code i am using file.delete_url instead i'm going to use the url_helper path in the view, car_image_path(file.id) --- thoughts??

Comment: no, never hardcode paths! for maintenance sake. I understand your need, I've made a dedicated class for this purpose, with the same delegate as above

Comment: I needed this to use route paths in application helpers

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `:show` method defined on the resource, therefore it doesn't create the `show` route, and doesn't give you the `car_image_path` method.

If you want the `car_image_path` method (which takes an argument, which should be which car image you want the path for), change the routing to something like this:

```
resources :car_images, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
```

However, if you're just looking for the path to all of the car images, `car_images_path` is what you're looking for.

Comment: im using the destroy path, which is the same as the show, with the method param correct? I have the :destroy path defined... So i don't understand why that route shows but the method doesnt work